# Log4j logging directly to elasticsearch server

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, log4j

I'm a bit confused on how can I put my log entries directly to `elasticsearch` (not logstash). So far I found a few appenders (`log4j.appender.SocketAppender`, `log4j.appender.server` etc.) that allow to send logs to remote host and also `ConversionPattern` possibility that seems to allow us to convert logs to "elastic-friendly" format, but this approach looks freaky... or do I mistake? Is this the one way to send logs to `elastic`?

So far I have a such config:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=9200
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=localhost
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
log4j.appender.server.layout.ConversionPattern={"debug_level":"%p","debug_timestamp":"%d{ISO8601}","debug_thread":"%t","debug_file":"%F", "debug_line":"%L","debug_message":"%m"}%n
```

But I get an error:

```
log4j:WARN Detected problem with connection: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
```

I can't find any useful example so I can't understand what do I do wrong and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: That's not possible. You need Logstash for that. If you want to use the deprecated log4j plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-log4j.html) it's ok, but we recommend writing log4j logs to files and use Filebeat to pick them up and send them to Elasticsearch.

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302421/logging-from-java-app-to-elk-without-need-for-parsing-logs

Comment: @diginoise `If you point logstash to this file`.. .so this means I'll write logs to a file and that's not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution that fits my requirements most. It's a [graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) .
Since it's build based on `elasticsearch` the usage is familiar so I was able to switch to it immediately.

To use it I added this dependency along with basic log4j2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and use `log4j2.json` configuration:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "status": "info",
    "name": "LOGGER",
    "packages": "org.graylog2.log4j2",
    "appenders": {
      "GELF": {
        "name": "GELF",
        "server": "log.myapp.com",
        "port": "12201",
        "hostName": "my-awsome-app",
        "JSONLayout": {
          "compact": "false",
          "locationInfo": "true",
          "complete": "true",
          "eventEol": "true",
          "properties": "true",
          "propertiesAsList": "true"
        },
        "ThresholdFilter": {
          "level": "info"
        }
      }
    },
    "loggers": {
      "logger": [
        {
          "name": "io.netty",
          "level": "info",
          "additivity": "false",
          "AppenderRef": {
            "ref": "GELF"
          }
        }        
      ],
      "root": {
        "level": "info",
        "AppenderRef": [
          {
            "ref": "GELF"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've written this appender here [Log4J2 Elastic REST Appender](https://github.com/magrossi/es-log4j2-appender) if you want to use it. It has the ability to buffer log events based on time and/or number of events before sending it to Elastic (using the _bulk API so that it sends it all in one go).
It has been published to Maven Central so it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: But it's not released yet?

Comment: I can't find it on Maven Central. Could you please share a link?

Comment: @KiraResari https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.magrossi/log4j2-elasticsearch-appender/1.0.1/jar?eh=

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to check out something new, my [Log4j2 Elasticsearch Appenders](https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch) will give you async logging in batches with failover.

Comment: Thank you, `graylog` is absolutely satisfying for me

Comment: But that one has a vulnerability (see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.appenders.log4j/log4j2-elasticsearch-core/1.5.5 )... Is that going to be fixed sometime?

Comment: @KiraResari, (easily replaceable) dependency has a vulnerability, not the library itself. Fixed in 1.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your logs by HTTP, with HttpAppender, see [Log4j Appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: I'm sure, person who investigates oportunity to store his app logs with elasticsearch and integrate log4j with it, is aware of such thing as http logging. Inappropriate as an answer to the question.
The worst approach to answer the question is something like that:
- How to install this thing?
- Do not install it or try installing it tomorrow.