# Logging from client swing Java app to ELK

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, citrix

We have fat Java swing client that runs in multiple instances on Citrix farm, we would like to send client logs to ElasticSearch server. Preferred way as I understand is to setup Logstash and point it to client logs. But our app is on Citrix so it is not desirable to have another app besides our app. Reading other answers like [Logging from Java app to ELK without need for parsing logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302421/logging-from-java-app-to-elk-without-need-for-parsing-logs?noredirect=1&lq=1) discourages building custom Java log appenders that would be used for sending logs to ElasticSearch.

Degrading application responsiveness is not an option and solution should be asynchronous. What are our options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my [Log4j2 Elasticsearch Appenders](https://github.com/rfoltyns/log4j2-elasticsearch). Out-of-the-box, it gives you async log delivery directly from the application to ES clusters, plus: failover, rolling indices, index template and security config.